# Animated Count Source Code

Tags: javascript, css, animation

So I'm fairly new to coding (very) and I found an animated counter on this one webpage that I would like to reproduce for my own. When looking into the source-code of the page, the css style seems to be installed from a javascript, however I don't know which one is correct. Would someone be able to help clarify which css upload I should use? Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

view-source:http://www.dmarealtors.com/advocacy

Counter Example: http://www.dmarealtors.com/advocacy

Comment: There are many JS libraries that do something similar, why not go with one of those? For example [this library](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) seems to be comparable

Answer (score 0):

This animation cannot be done with css alone. If you look at the DOM when the page is loaded, you can see, how the value inside the html element is changed.

So, this is simply a loop, which sets a new value every few ms.

```
var element = document.getElementById("counter"); //or whatever id your element has

var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    counter += 1000;
    element.innerHTML = counter;
    if(counter == 150000) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 50); //wait 50ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have found what you asked for, it has to be the file as following in the picture[image]

Now, I will explain how I can find it, you have to first identify where is the location in HTML file. After then, you will take the elements class or id, in you case, here is what I have found[image]

the class name is "field field-name-field-counter ... ". After you have found the name, open notepad++, search for that name in every single css file

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you so much for walking through this!!